# Difference between a changeset and a patch?

Tags: import, patch, mercurial, changeset

What is the difference a changeset and a patch?

I was using hg today and I noticed the import command mentions that it is used to "import an ordered set of patches."

What is a patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changeset typically refers to the internal representation.  Thus, `hg unbundle`, which processes mercurial-specific files, "applies one or more changegroup files."  A changegroup is simply a group of changesets.

Patches are plain text in standard formats (e.g. produced by [`diff`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff)).  Note that the [`patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) command can be used to process these plaintext files (independent of revision control).